# Should all gdpr related documents be translated to all official EU languages?

Tags: privacy, gdpr, translation

I wrote application localized in Ukrainian language , which is not one of the official European Union languages. Since I reside in the EU territory I need to comply with gdpr. This application is targeted only to people who know Ukrainian language. This brings me to a question in order to comply with General data protection regulation I need to provide users with human understandable privacy policy. Can this privacy policy the only in Ukrainian language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(EU) 2016/679 (GDPR) is [available in 24 languages](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/eli/reg/2016/679/oj). It wouldn't be practical for everyone communicating with EU citizens to be obliged to translate to all of them.

Article 12 in Chapter 3 section 1 specifies :

> The controller shall take appropriate measures to provide any
>   information referred to in Articles 13 and 14 and any communication
>   under Articles 15 to 22 and 34 relating to processing to the data
>   subject in a concise, transparent, intelligible and easily accessible
>   form, using clear and plain language

If your application is available only in Ukranian and only people who understand Ukranian will be able to use it, your policies and responses to customer enquiries should also be in Ukrainian - but in a form that's "concise, transparent and easily accessible".